# BISON FLEX. Unexpected output when an input file is provided

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to create a calculator with flex and bison which gets a set of operations (results are assigned to variables). The calculator uses a memory to store these variables. When I do this calculations via terminal (stdin keyboard) everything works fine. However, when I try to use a file, nothing is stored in the memory.

I have a .y and .l

This is what I have specified in the .y.

```
extern FILE* yyin;
```

And in the main method:

```
yyin = fopen(argv[1], "rt");
yyparse ();     
listTofile(list, argv[2]); //method that backups memory into a file
fclose(yyin);
```

When I for example type A = 2 + 2, the file will store the name variable and the result. This perfectly work when the prompt ask me an instruction.
However, when a file is provided parser detects all but does not store anything (checked using flex -d)

Comment: What is `"rt"`? I don;t know those flags. Check the return value of `fopen`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie it's the same as ```r```. It is an open mode. I've already tried both methods. The file is opened, the issue is that the program behaves in a different way if I manually introduce data instead of provide it through a file

Comment: @razexx, Paul was somewhat gently telling you that `"rt"` is *not* a (standard) open mode.  To open a file for reading in text mode, use `"r"`.  Moreover, if that is indeed the issue, then checking the return value of `fopen()`, as he suggested, would allow you to detect that.

Comment: The code shown does not have an option for not specifying a file. If there is no command line argument, the `fopen` call will segfault. However, if the `fopen` fails, as suggested by the above comments, `yyin` will be NULL, and `yylex` will then read from `stdin`. None of that has anything to do with the output, which is presumably hidden in the function `listTofile` whose source you don't show.

Answer (score 0):

With flex, generally you need to call `yyrestart(yyin);` to switch to a new input source to reset all the buffering source.  That said, if you never read anything from yyin before your fopen call, this should not make any difference, as there should not be any cached buffer contents to reset.